# Is there a way to re-position the slider/dropdowns in dynamic map using Holoviews?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, holoviews, holoviz

I have a dynamic map containing many tif files, when I create the dynamic map it creates a time slider shown to the right of the image (which is what I want). The only thing is I wish to be able to reposition this slider to be above my image and maybe apply some styling to it. Is there a way to do this?

[Example Shown Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4IOS.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

So since HoloViews v1.13.x the widgets are indeed customizable as they are now built on top of the Panel library. To change the location you can set `hv.output(widget_location=<option>)` where the valid options are:

```
['left', 'bottom', 'right', 'top', 'top_left', 'top_right',
 'bottom_left', 'bottom_right', 'left_top', 'left_bottom',
 'right_top', 'right_bottom']
```

If you need further customization you can drop down to Panel itself as shown [here](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/panes/HoloViews.html)

Comment: I actually have the same question. The widget_location doesn't allow float tuples, so you can't place the widget on the plot, only on one of the sides. I can't find anything on panel either. Is it even possible?

Comment: Without custom CSS it's not possible no.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? Or maybe point me to the right content that can help.